# Class Does not Return Value

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services

Good day,

I have this Code , now i want it to return the data to return the Fullname, Id_type, Id_Number, Dateof birth, BVN

Now i want it to pull information from a Webservice API and then show into text Fields

My class Looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class Customer
{
    public string fullname { get; set; }
    public string id_type { get; set; }
    public string id_number { get; set; }
    public string dob { get; set; }
    public string bvn { get; set; }
}
```

And the code Looks like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web.Services;


[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class FetchInformationBVNService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    string constring = @"Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=*****;Integrated Security=True";
    public FetchInformationBVNService()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public Customer GetCustomerNameWithBVN(string bvn)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            cn.Open();
            string q = "select fullname,id_type,id_number,date_ofbirth,bvn from account_info where bvn =@bvn";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bvn", bvn);
                using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        return new Customer
                        {
                            fullname = rd["fullname"].ToString(),
                            id_type = rd["id_type"].ToString(),
                            id_number = rd["id_number"].ToString(),
                            dob = rd["date_ofbirth"].ToString(),
                            bvn = rd["bvn"].ToString()
                        };
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Now i get the error Below :

`Not all Code paths return a value on line 34`, Like what is wrong with it?

Comment: I think you forgor to add these `()` brackets after the new object when you create the new `Customer` object and return it to the function returned value.

Comment: You need to tell the method what to return in the case when `rd.Read()` returns false. You could, for example, return `null`, to indicate that the Customer was not found.

Comment: @Azhy parentheses are optional in an object initializer when using the property-setting syntax using curly braces; that's not the issue here.

Comment: Why do you use `while` and not `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rd.Read()` is `false`, no return statement will be executed. Since you want to return only one customer, use an `if` statement instead of a loop

```
if (rd.Read())
{
    return new Customer
    {
        fullname = rd["fullname"].ToString(),
        id_type = rd["id_type"].ToString(),
        id_number = rd["id_number"].ToString(),
        dob = rd["date_ofbirth"].ToString(),
        bvn = rd["bvn"].ToString()
    };
}
return null; // In case no record is returned.
```

Or return an empty customer

```
return new Customer();
```

Note: Even if you know that `rd.Read()` cannot fail, C# doesn't and concludes the method would exit without returning a value. Therefore satisfy C# and add this additional return statement.

Answer (score 0):

If `rd.Read()` doesn't return any data, the `return` line will be skipped, so you might want to throw an exception or return null in that case.

By the way, are you trying to return multiple customers? You have your return statement in a `while` loop; if you want multiple return values you will need to change the return type of your function to `IEnumerable<Customer>` and replace `return` with `yield return`.

Comment: No I just want a scenario when i type say the BVN it would return the data of the customer and populate the information from the database which contains the Fullname, Id_type, Id_Number, Dateof birth, BVN